# How to do a dynamic function for a wordpress theme options

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress theme, and I'm wondering how to do a more clean code when displaying options in wp-admin.

Right now, my code is the following:

```
...    

<?php $field_key = 'logo_retina'; if ( ! isset( $options[$field_key] ) ) $options[$field_key] = '';?>
                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Logo HQ', 'yes' ); ?></th>
                    <td><input id="<?php echo $field_key; ?>" class="regular-text" type="text" name="yes_theme_options[<?php echo $field_key; ?>]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options[$field_key] ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

            <?php $field_key = 'logo_non_retina'; if ( ! isset( $options[$field_key] ) ) $options[$field_key] = ''; ?>
                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Logo SQ', 'yes' ); ?></th>
                    <td><input id="<?php echo $field_key; ?>" class="regular-text" type="text" name="yes_theme_options[<?php echo $field_key; ?>]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options[$field_key] ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

            <?php $field_key = 'slogan_retina'; if ( ! isset( $options[$field_key])) $options[$field_key] = ''; ?>
                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Slogan HQ', 'yes' ); ?></th>
                    <td><input id="<?php echo $field_key; ?>" class="regular-text" type="text" name="yes_theme_options[<?php echo $field_key; ?>]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options[$field_key] ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

...
```

The original code is more than this three forms.

What I want to do is display this options, but dynamically. I mean, with just one function in php, for example. I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the function I use when defining custom options for a theme.

To add a dynamic field to the custom options, you add to the **$options** array with the following fields:

**"name"** is the display that will show up in the admin panel. For example "Facebook URL"

**"desc"** is the text that gets displayed bellow the field. For example "The full HTTP URL to your Facebook page"

**"id"** is the variable you're going to use in your theme when you're getting the settings values.

**"type"** is the type of field that is going to get displayed. These options can be "text" for a text field, "textarea" for a textarea field or "heading" for a heading break. The heading break lets you categorize the different fields.

Only **"name"** and **"id"** are required.

```
$options =  
array( 
    array("name" => " Options", "type" => "title"),
    array("type" => "open"), 
    array("name" => "", "desc" => "", "id" => "", "type" => "text"),
    array( "type" => "close")
);  

function mytheme_add_admin() {

    global $shortname, $options;

    if($_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__)) {
        if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'save') {

            foreach($options as $value) {
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); 
            }

            foreach($options as $value) {
                if(isset($_REQUEST[ $value['id']])) { 
                    update_option($value['id'], $_REQUEST[$value['id']]); 
                } else { 
                    delete_option( $value['id'] ); 
                } 
            }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
            die;

        } else if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'reset') {

            foreach($options as $value) {
                delete_option($value['id']); 
            }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&reset=true");
            die;

        }
    }

    //add_menu_page(get_bloginfo('name') . " Options", "Theme Settings", 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin', '', '63.3');
    add_submenu_page('themes.php', get_bloginfo('name') . " Options", 'Theme Settings', 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');

}

function mytheme_admin() {
    global $shortname, $options;
    if($_REQUEST['saved']) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.get_bloginfo('name').' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
    if($_REQUEST['reset']) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.get_bloginfo('name').' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';
?>

<div class="wrap">
<h2><?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?> Settings</h2>

    <form method="post" style="background-color:#f8f8f8; padding:10px; margin-top: 10px;">

    <?php foreach ($options as $value) {
    switch ( $value['type'] ) {

    case "open":
    ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0">

    <?php break;

    case "close":
    ?>

    </table>

    <?php break;

    case 'text':
    ?>


    <tr>
    <td width="20%" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong></td>
    <td width="80%"><input style="width:400px;" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings($value['id'])); } else { echo stripslashes($value['std']); } ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small></td>
    </tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <?php
        break;
        case 'heading':
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="2" valign="middle"><h3><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    break;

    case 'textarea':
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td width="20%" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong></td>
    <td width="80%"><textarea name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" style="width:400px; height:200px;" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" cols="" rows=""><?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings($value['id'])); } else { echo stripslashes($value['std']); } ?></textarea></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small></td>
    </tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>    
    <?php break;

    }
    }
    ?>

    <input name="save" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save changes" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
    </form>

    <?php
    }


add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin');
```

Here's how you get the settings value from your custom settings:

```
<?php
    global $options;
    foreach ($options as $value) {
        if(get_settings($value['id']) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = stripslashes($value['std']); } else { $$value['id'] = stripslashes(get_settings($value['id'])); }
    }
?>
```

You place that on the top of the file you need to get the settings. The variables will be the same as the "ID" you defined above. If the ID is "**facebook**", the PHP variable will then be **$facebook**.